# How I can prove the function $f(t)$ is increasing (decreasing) in $t$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, exponential-function, monotone-functions

How can I demonstrate a mathematical proof that the following function $f(t)$

$$f(t)=-\frac{1}{t}\ln\left( e^{\alpha t}\left(2\beta-\frac{3\beta }{2} e^{\frac{\alpha t}{2}}\right)\right)$$

is decreasing in $t$, where $t\geq0$, $0\leq \beta \leq 1$ and $\alpha <0$. 
since

$f'(t)=\frac{\ln \left(e^{\alpha  t} \left(2 \beta -\frac{3}{2} \beta 
   e^{\frac{\alpha  t}{2}}\right)\right)}{t^2}-\frac{e^{\alpha  (-t)}
   \left(\alpha  e^{\alpha  t} \left(2 \beta -\frac{3}{2} \beta 
   e^{\frac{\alpha  t}{2}}\right)-\frac{3}{4} \alpha  \beta  e^{\frac{3
   \alpha  t}{2}}\right)}{t \left(2 \beta -\frac{3}{2} \beta 
   e^{\frac{\alpha  t}{2}}\right)}$

it is always negative.

Is there an importance to alpha and beta values in the proof of decreasing function for t?

Is this proof convincing of the particular situation?

In particular, $$ f(t)=-\frac{1}{t}\ln(\beta e^{\alpha t})=\alpha-\frac{\ln \beta}{t}$$  where $t\geq0$, $0\leq \beta \leq 1$ and $\alpha <0$.

$$f'(t)=\frac{\ln \beta}{t^2}$$
as $0\leq \beta \leq 1$  is smaller than 1 and the logarithm is negative.

Hence $f'(t)$ is negative for any $t$

Comment: Calculate derivative and show that either $f'(t)>0$ or $f'(t)<0$?

Comment: @freakish see new update

Comment: Hint: It would be easier if you first use logarithmic identities.

Comment: @Levi How . could you explain more.

Comment: For $x,y>0$, we have $$\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y).$$ Hence, $$f(t)=-\frac{1}{t} \ln (e^{\alpha t}(2\beta-\frac{3}{2}\beta e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}t})) = -\alpha -\frac{1}{t} \ln(2\beta-\frac{3}{2}\beta e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}t}) = -\alpha -\frac{1}{t} \ln(\frac{1}{2}\beta) -\frac{1}{t} \ln(4-3 e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}t}).$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution. I did my best, but the problem is difficult because of the mix of algebraic and logarithm. I tried to prove that the derivative is negative, but there is a detail in the end that I could not fix.

$$f'(t)=\frac{2 \log \left(b \left(2 e^{a t}-\frac{3}{2} e^{\frac{3 a t}{2}}\right)\right)+a t \left(\frac{4}{4-3 e^{\frac{a t}{2}}}-3\right)}{2 t^2}$$
As denominator is positive for any $t$ we will discuss the numerator:

First part is negative because when the argument of logarithm is smaller than $1$ for any $t<0$

$b \left(2 e^{a t}-\frac{3}{2} e^{\frac{3 a t}{2}}\right)<1$

Indeed, $a<0$ means that both $e^{at}$ and $e^{\frac{3 a t}{2}}$ are less than $1$ therefore, for any $t>0$ we have $2 e^{a t}-\frac{3}{2} e^{\frac{3 a t}{2}}<\frac{1}{2}$

as $0\le b\le 1$ it follows that the product is smaller than $1$ and the logarithm is negative.

The second part has a factor $at$ which is negative for the conditions on variables and parameters

$$\frac{4}{4-3 e^{\frac{a t}{2}}}-3=-\frac{9 e^{\frac{a t}{2}}-8}{3 e^{\frac{a t}{2}}-4}>0$$

substitute $u=e^{\frac{a t}{2}}$ and solve

$-\dfrac{9 u-8}{3 u-4}>0\to \dfrac{8}{9}<u<\dfrac{4}{3}$

which is $\dfrac{8}{9}<e^{\frac{a t}{2}}<\dfrac{4}{3}$

that is $\log\dfrac{8}{9}<\dfrac{a t}{2}<\log\dfrac{4}{3}$

which for $a<0$ has the solution $0<t<\frac{2 \log \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)}{a}$

That is about $0<t<-\dfrac{0.24}{a}$

This means that in this interval we are sure that the derivative is negative, for greater values of $t$ the second part of the numerator of the derivative is positive and I don't know if it is, in absolute value, greater or smaller than the first part that is negative for any $t$

Hope this helps anyway

Comment: Is this proof convincing of the particular situation

In particular, $$ f(t)=-\frac{1}{t}\ln(\beta e^{\alpha t})=\alpha-\frac{\ln \beta}{t}$$  where $t\geq0$, $0\leq \beta \leq 1$ and $\alpha <0$.    

$$f'(t)=\frac{\ln \beta}{t^2}$$
as $0\leq \beta \leq 1$  is smaller than 1 and the logarithm is negative.

Hence $f'(t)$ is negative for any $t$